# remove duplicate document on the basis of condition in mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following document

```
{
"_id": "5c6eabcc813ea3fabf972eaa",
"employee_id": "abc",
"name": "singh",
"salary": 0
},
{
"_id": "5c6eabcc813ea3fabf972eaa",
"employee_id": "abc",
"name": "singh",
"salary": 0
},
{
"_id": "5c6eabcc813ea3fabf972eaa",
"employee_id": "abc",
"name": "singh",
"salary": {
"_id": "5c80ddc1ef020744825efe9c",
"month": 2,
"year": 2019
}
```

I want to delete document if salary.month not equal to 2 for same "_id" value as given above dataset . I am using aggregation pipeline .Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The query given below can do it for you.

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').deleteMany({ $where : function() { return (this._id === this.salary._id && this.salary.month === 2) }})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply.  can you please tell me how can you do lookup on condition means  join only when condition satisfied

Comment: Sorry. I'm unable to understand your comment. Can you briefly tell me what you are looking for?

Comment: I have two  collections  and I want to do left outer join only when 2nd collections field value satified some conditions(for exaplme join only when salary >10)

Comment: You can use $lookup and $match to do it. refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ for an example. $lookup should have join condition and $match contains salary > 10.

Comment: this is condition after join. I need join only when condition satisfied

Comment: Do the match first, and then join on the result.